# Vue 3/Typescript: Cannot find module xxx or its corresponding type declarations. Vetur(2307)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, compiler-errors, vuejs3

I am trying to import a .vue component in **Vue 3 / Typescript** but I keep getting this error:

`Cannot find module '@/components/Fields/IconButton' or its corresponding type declarations. Vetur(2307)`

If I import the .vue component as `@/components/Fields/IconButton.vue` it works, but it does not work if I import it as `@/components/Fields/IconButton`

What am I doing wrong?

My **tsconfig.json** :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My **shims-vue.d.ts** under src/ :

```
/* eslint-disable */
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

Many thanks. :)

Comment: Including the `.vue` extension is actually [recommended](https://twitter.com/youyuxi/status/1288859415878283264): `You should always use the .vue extension when importing Vue components, as omitting the extension creates numerous problems for static analysis tools. It was a mistake to allow it in vue-cli and we will likely disable it in the future.` -- Evan You (July 30, 2020)